# Entity Framework 5 Get All method

Tags: entity-framework

In our EF implementation for Brand New Project, we have GetAll method in Repository. But, as our Application Grows, we are going to have let's say 5000 Products, Getting All the way it is, would be Performance Problem. Wouldn't it ?

if So, what is good implementation to tackle this future problem?

Any help will be hightly appreciated.

Comment: What does your `GetAll()` method return?  An `IQueryable<T>`, an `IEnumerable<T>`, or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how your repository class is set up.  If you're performing the query immediately, i.e. if your `GetAll()` method returns something like `IEnumerable<T>` or `IList<T>`, then yes, that could easily be a performance problem, and you should generally avoid that sort of thing unless you really want to load all records at once.

On the other hand, if your `GetAll()` method returns an `IQueryable<T>`, then there may not be a problem at all, depending on whether you trust the people writing queries.  Returning an `IQueryable<T>` would allow callers to further refine the search criteria before the SQL code is actually generated.  Performance-wise, it would only be a problem if developers using your code didn't apply any filters before executing the query.  If you trust them enough to give them enough rope to hang themselves (and potentially take your database performance down with them), then just returning `IQueryable<T>` might be good enough.

If you don't trust them, then, as others have pointed out, you could limit the number of records returned by your query by using the `Skip()` and `Take()` extension methods to implement simple pagination, but note that it's possible for records to slip through the cracks if people make changes to the database before you move on to the next page.  Making pagination work seamlessly with an ever-changing database is much harder than a lot of people think.

Another approach would be to replace your `GetAll()` method with one that requires the caller to apply a filter before returning results:

```
public IQueryable<T> GetMatching<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter)
{
  // Replace myQuery with Context.Set<T>() or whatever you're using for data access
  return myQuery.Where(filter);
}
```

and then use it like `var results = GetMatching(x => x.Name == "foo");`, or whatever you want to do.  Note that this could be easily bypassed by calling `GetMatching(x => true)`, but at least it makes the intention clear.  You could also combine this with the first method to put a firm cap on the number of records returned.

My personal feeling, though, is that all of these ways of limiting queries are just insurance against bad developers getting their hands on your application, and if you have bad developers working on your project, they'll find a way to cause problems no matter what you try to do.  So my vote is to just return an `IQueryable<T>` and trust that it will be used responsibly.  If people abuse it, take away the `GetAll()` method and give them training-wheels methods like `GetRecentPosts(int count)` or `GetPostsWithTag(string tag, int count)` or something like that, where the query logic is out of their hands.

Comment: Thx Jeremy and sorry for getting too late to this post. Your explanation makes sense since this is matter of how you implement, but techniques you mentioned with other folks are worth using. Thx to all of you.

Answer (score 3):

It could become a performance problem if get all is enumerating on the collection, thus causing the entire data set to be returned in an `IEnumerable`. This all depends on the number of joins, the size of the data set, if you have lazy loading enabled, how SQL Server performs, just to name a few.

Some people will say this is not desired, you could have `GetAll()` return an `IQueryable` which would defer the query until something caused the collection to be filled by going to SQL. That way you could filter the results with other `Where()`, `Take()`, `Skip()`, etc statements to allow for paging without having to retrieve all 5000+ products from the database.

Comment: Yes, _both_ filtering an paging! +1 I'd like to add that EF requires an `OrderBy()` statement before `Skip()`.

Answer (score 0):

What your referring to is known as paging, and it's pretty trivial to do using LINQ via the [Skip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358985.aspx)/[Take](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062.aspx) methods.

EF queries are lazily loaded which means they won't actually hit the database until they are evaluated so the following would only pull the first 10 rows after skipping the first 10

```
context.Table.Skip(10).Take(10);
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to improve this is by using pagination

```
context.Products.Skip(n).Take(m);
```